# Remove fill text from ggplot map

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, fill

i have the code below which displays US counties based on fill=EQI. This is ok, but how can i remove the fill text when i make mouse hover on the map and keep only the variable County_Name_ID as text? I want to maintain fill only next to the map.

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlotly ({
    p<-  ggplot(DF, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group,text=County_Name_ID,fill = EQI))
    p<- p+  geom_polygon()
    p<-p+ scale_fill_continuous("Measure Density")
    ggplotly(p)
  })
```

Comment: Without reproducible example it's hard to understand what you mean by "remove the fill text when i make mouse hover on the map"

Comment: When i click on the map on a certain spot i take as text: County_Name_ID and EQI. I want to get as text only the County_Name_ID and hide the EQI.

Comment: Just reading the documentation in `?ggplotly` I would guess you need `ggplotly(p, tooltip = 'County_Name_ID')`, but yes a reproducible example would make your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can set your tooltip within the ggplotly function. Give this a try:

`ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("County_Name_ID"))`

Comment: I was searching exactly for this. I did not use reproducible example because it would probably make the topic more complex than it really is. Anyway thanks a lot.